# convert from java6 to java8 using stream and filter

Tags: java, java-stream, porting

I have the below code and need to convert to java8 using stream and filter.Can someone please help?

```
      for (CertEntity entity : listOfExpiredCert){
            if (entity!=null && entity.getCertVldToDt()!=null){
                if (entity.getCertSerNum()!=null && entity.getCertSerNum().equals(baseObject.getCertSerNum())){
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    if (entity.getCertVldToDt()!=null && entity.getCertVldToDt().compareTo(baseDate)>0){
                        entityWithLatestDate = entity;
                    }
                    else if (entity.getCertVldToDt()!=null && entity.getCertVldToDt().compareTo(baseDate)<0){
                        entityWithLatestDate = baseObject;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Questions will be received better if you include what you've tried and where you are stuck. Currently the question isn't very generic and - as such - little use to anyone else.

Comment: It seems like variable `entityWithLatestDate` is being randomly modified. You are not checking its current value before assigning the new one. First, please explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: That is a business logic

Comment: Why do it all?  The logic here is easy to follow, even easier if you remove the unneeded getCertVldToDt() != null checks in the inner if's.  You don't gain anything by switching to a different methodology except added complexity.

Comment: @satya `a business logic` - It doesn't explain why you're assigning `entityWithLatestDate` in the way that is dependent on the order of the list entities? The list is sorted?

Comment: Asking the same question again after it getting downvoted, close voted, delete voted is **not** appreciated here at all. This community has its rules and practices, and the negative feedback you receive is intended to tell you to act differently, not to double down. Note that continuing on this path will get your account banned from asking questions at some point, so seriously: don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

if I understand correctly then you are just trying to find CertEntity with the latest CertVldToDt and matching CertSerNum to some baseObject. This code should do it:

```
entityWithLatestDate = listOfExpiredCert.stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(entity -> entity.getCertSerNum() != null)
            .filter(entity -> entity.getCertVldToDt() != null)
            .filter(entity -> entity.getCertSerNum().equals(baseObject.getCertSerNum()))
            .filter(entity -> entity.getCertVldToDt().compareTo(baseDate) > 0)
            .max(Comparator.comparing(CertEntity::getCertVldToDt))
            .orElse(baseObject);
```

Comment: I have a continue in the if loop.how to handle that?

Comment: That continue statement just excluding entities with unmatching CertSerNum from searching, 2nd and 4th .filter() does the same

Comment: It is filtering and will add to the lost eventually but its not excluding?

Comment: What is the purpose of max() here?why cant we remove max()

Comment: .filter() staqtements excludes no matching your conditions, .max() finds entity with latest date. If you remove it, you will have collection of entites with CertVldToDt after baseDate. You want to select only one, so .max() is selecting latest

Comment: So in the for loop there is continue .what continue does is it goes to for loop skipping other code.But in your code that is not happening

Comment: Continue statement causes the loop to immediately jump to the next iteration of the loop. In my code .filter() statements do it

Comment: But in the initial code if the condition matches then it goes to continue and goes to next iteration of loop.i do no think so same happens in your code.That is if the condition matches will it go to next iteration of loop?

Comment: Exactly . If the condition in .filter matches it is equivalent to passing iteration

Comment: But I did not get the expected out put using your code.The “continue” logic is missing something in your code

Comment: Can you please propose any alternate code using filter,stream

Comment: @LordSkin Welcome to stack overflow. Upvoted your answer for your patience. But for your own mental health here on stack overflow,  I recommend you turn here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258279/1531124 and do some reading.